# Jodatime time difference gives negative result

Tags: java, date, datetime

I calculating time difference between two dates. One coming from database and another current time.

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
Date dbDate = loader.getsuccessDate();
DateTime d1 = new DateTime (currentDate.getTime());
DateTime d2 = new DateTime (dbDate.getTime());

System.out.println(Hours.hoursBetween(d1 - d2).getHours);

// gives results as -285
```

How to convert the negative results to positive value.

Comment: The mathematical conversion would be a multiplication with `-1`, I think... Would that be correct here? I mean is `285` the correct result? I cannot tell you that without example data...

Comment: Please post compilable code when not asking about a compile error. I get *The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.DateTime*. It means that I am unsure which code exactly is giving you the negative result, a very big disadvantage for anyone trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the result is w.r.t. minute. I would do as following.

```
int totalTimeInMinutes = Hours.hoursBetween(d1 - d2).getHours;
int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;
if (totalTimeInMinutes < 0)
    totalTimeInMinutes *= -1;

hour = totalTimeInMinutes / 60;
minute = totalTimeInMinutes % 60;
```